# inject render method into template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Must the render method of a Vue component be used exclusively or can it be combined with a template? Most of my component can be rendered using a template but just need a small part of it to be rendered using code. If this is possible how can I combine the render method output with the template?

Example in component:

```
<template>
   <table>
      <tr>
        // use render method here
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="row in rows">
        // use render method here
      </tr>  
   </table>
</template>
```

Need render method in spots above to loop through the array `$scopedSlots.column` and render each `<th>` and `<td>` based on multiple `<templates v-slot:column={row}>` provided by parent.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to combine them? Please, provide the example that explains your case.

Comment: Do you really need the `render` function?

Comment: Updated original question with example.

Comment: And you cannot move that into an own component with a `render` function?

Comment: Just a note. Altarnative, simpler and by design solution is to use [slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can either use the render function or a template - but not both. They can not be combined.

What you could do to make your example work is to use the `v-html`-directive, which updates the `innerHTML` of an element https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-html.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  data: {
    rows: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']
  },
  methods: {
    renderRow(row) {
      return `<td>${row}</td>`;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="row in rows" v-html="renderRow(row)">
    
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's dangerous to use `v-html` if you are not 100% sure that the data (`row`) is not malicious. It's much better to use a separate component with a `render()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same challenge as well. Which is how I came to your question.

As others have said, it seems you can either use a template or render function but not both.

My suggestion would be to have a component handle only the render function, while the parent component can use the template method

So, Per your example

```
<template>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <component-using-only-render-method />
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="row in rows">
        <component-using-only-render-method />
      </tr>  
   </table>
</template>
```

I think its the best of both worlds with minimal compromise

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tip about warpping them in a new component from [@Audacitus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962781/inject-render-method-into-template/68334592#68334592) and using the [React-like functional component](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function#functional-components) syntax:

```
import type { FunctionalComponent, VNode } from 'vue';

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962781/inject-render-method-into-template/77975171#77975171
interface Props { renderer: VNode }
const RenderFunction: FunctionalComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => props.renderer;
RenderFunction.props = { renderer: { type: Object, required: true } };
export default RenderFunction;
```

Usage:

```js
<template>
<RenderFunction :renderer="renderer">
</template>

<script setup lang="tsx">
const renderer = <div></div>;
</script>
```

Also note that keep reactivity is your responsibility when using render function over template:

```js
<template>
<RenderFunction :renderer="renderer">
</template>

<script setup lang="tsx">
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';
const value = ref(true);
setInterval(() => value.value = !value.value, 1000);
const renderer = computed(() => <div>{value}</div>);
</script>
```